# Beginner tutorial - cannot run roscore

Tags: ros, thread, beginner-tutorials, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm incredibly new to ROS (and I'm no Ubuntu master, either) and I've been following the beginner tutorial to the letter. When I try to run roscore (at the appropriate point) I get this print-out:

```
... logging to /home/liz/.ros/log/336fd2b2-d7fe-11e1-8326-e02a82da7f54/roslaunch-ubuntu-3375.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:52747/
ros_comm version 1.8.10

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [3391]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ubuntu:11311/

setting /run_id to 336fd2b2-d7fe-11e1-8326-e02a82da7f54
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3404]
started core service [/rosout]
```

The system then hangs. Running roswtf gives this:

```
ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:
 * beginner_tutorials: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * std_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * roscpp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (Windows Installer version). I've tried fixing any network configurations (as suggested by the tutorial) and fixing manifest.xml to include the matching -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib". I can't find anything else that fits the problem I'm having, and I'd appreciate any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39996/beginner-tutorial---cannot-run-roscore/) by [lizfltn](https://answers.ros.org/users/2935/lizfltn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-27**:
Could you reformat your question a bit? Please prefix each line you copied from the console with '    ' (four spaces). See also [markdown/syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe that the actually system hangs, roscore is probably running. Open a new console and type `rostopic list` to verify.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No answer is accepted so I am posting
I have learned that you should always run rxgraph to see whats really going in ROS(that's what I do)
In your case if it shows /rosout as a node then your roscore is running.

---

Originally posted by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) with karma: 231 on 2012-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1